# How do I delete anything after 6 characters in a String?

Tags: java, string, syntax, char

So I have a bunch of strings that only need to contain the first 6 characters. Is there an algorithm than can take a string and remove anything that comes after the 6th character?

Comment: short answer yes. You should provide a sample of what your tried to do for more help.

Comment: Yes, there is [`String.substring(int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int))

Answer (score 3):

Just use String's `substring()` method

```
String value = "abcdefghijkl";
String newValue = value.substring(0, 6); // "abcdef"
```

[substring reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Answer (score 2):

```
str = str.substring(0, 6);
```

That will cut the string to the 6th letter.

Comment: It generate 5 characters string.

Comment: Sorry my bad, change 5 to 6

Answer (score 1):

use substring method:

```
public String removeExtra(String s)
{
    return s.substring(0,6);
}
```